# how to create a custom design for adding a new user in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

i am new to symfony i would like to create a custom design for adding a new user. how to create a custom design for adding new user in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin .

```
http://localhost/xxxx/web/backend_dev.php/guard/users/new
```

i am able to add a new user in this link. but i need to change the design. where i can find the form in which i can change the design. i am not able to find any template folder inside my sfGuardUser module. which is located in `plugins\sfDoctrineGuardPlugin\modules\sfGuardUser` any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sfDoctrineGuardPlugin uses the regular admin generator, so you need to add files to your backend app:

```
apps/mybackendapp/
└── modules
    └── sfGuardUser
        └── templates
            └── newSuccess.php
```

Comment: I found those files in  `cache\backend\dev\modules\autoSfGuardUser`. i just created a folder in  `apps/mybackendapp/modules/sfGuardUser` and copied necessary files to this folder from cache folder. the form was named as _form.php. and i changed the design and now it works for me i don't know whether i am doing it in a right way.. any way thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your app users to use the backend admin generator to create new users, you may want to check out sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin, which gives your users the added benefit of registering as a new user and giving you some control over the whole process.  It also comes loaded with the forms you seek and email confirmation etc... I also use it in my own "User" module which allows certain registered users the ability to create child-users for their account.  sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin extends sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.